# How to connect VBA with a Rumba 3270 emulator

Tags: vba, excel, mainframe, 3270

I have come to the knowledge that to connect to Rumba 3270 mainframe I need to incorporate

`"Ehlapi32.DLL`"

However when I googled around I found a ton of functions which I not sure how to use. I have the following code to connect, but its returning connection error.

```
Sub fConnect()
    nRT = 0
    Call hllapi(1, ByVal "A", 0, nRT)

    If nRT <> 0 Then 'if not made connection display a Error
            MsgBox "Connection Error. Try again"
    Else
            strConectado = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Below is the hllapi function

```
Declare Function hllapi Lib "C:\Program Files\NetManage\System\Ehlapi32.DLL" (Func As Integer, ByVal lpszData As String, Length As Integer, Value As Integer) As Integer
Declare Function OSGetPrivateProfileString% Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetPrivateProfileStringA" (ByVal AppName$, ByVal KeyName$, ByVal keydefault$, ByVal ReturnString$, ByVal NumBytes As Integer, ByVal FileName$)
' HLLAPI FUNCTION DECLARATIONS

Public nRT
Public strConectado As Boolean

Public Enum ImpulseKeyEnum
    ike_enter = 0
    ike_f1 = 1
    ike_F2 = 2
    IKE_F3 = 3
    ike_F4 = 4
    ike_F5 = 5
    ike_F6 = 6
    ike_F7 = 7
    ike_F8 = 8
    ike_F9 = 9
    ike_F10 = 10
    ike_F11 = 11
    ike_F12 = 12
    ike_F13 = 13
    ike_BackTab = 93
    ike_Left = 94
    ike_right = 95
    ike_UP = 96
    ike_Down = 97
    ike_Tab = 98
    ike_clearfield = 99
    ike_Attention = 100
End Enum

Public Enum PositionSearch
    ika_right = 1
    ika_Left = 2
End Enum
```

When I run the program with RUMBA open using F8 key, it shows error, The "nRT" variable is getting set as "1" instead of "0".

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: No error as such but goes into the msg box ""Connection Error. Try again""

Comment: The "nRT" variable is getting set as "1" instead of "0". Main issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you giving the name of your connection as "A". Unless it is not "A" it will give error.

First give name to the session short name as "A". Then run again.